# Cancel AsyncTask when HTTPPost fails?

Tags: android, http-post, android-asynctask

I'm trying to cancel my AsyncTask when connecting to the server fails. I tried `cancel()`, but the `onPostExecute()` method still gets called, instead of `onCancelled()`.

This is what I have inside `doInBackground()`:

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i("ping", "doInBackground() started");

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);

        HttpResponse response;
        HttpEntity entity;

            try {
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.6/ping/login.php");

                List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", getEmail()));
                nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", getPassword()));

                post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

                response = client.execute(post);
                entity = response.getEntity();

                InputStream iStream = entity.getContent();
                read(iStream);
                iStream.close();

                if(entity != null)
                    entity.consumeContent();

                Log.i("ping", "doInBackground() vervolgd");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("tvsping", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                cancel(true);
            }
        return null;
    }
```

I'm trying to see what happens when the server can't be reached (I'm shutting it down, so there's no way my phone is getting any response) and I get `IOException: the connection was reset`.

Any ideas how I should check if the connection isn't made?

**update**
I solved this like Tanmay suggested, with a boolean. But I have another problem:
Every time doInBackground() is called it takes about three minutes to stop, when it can't find the servers. Everything is fine when it can reach the server, but I can't have this taking 3 minutes before the user is notified of anything (I could do a background process, but still a 3 minute wating bar is no good neither)

Any ideas what is wrong with my code? This can't be normal, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `doInBackground()` method you are returning a `String` .You can return `null` if your `HTTPPost` fails.And then in `onPostExecute()` method just check what are you getting, if the `String` is null dont do anything which you really want and on successful running do your UI work

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Any idea how I could 'detect' this problem faster? Because now it takes roughly three minutes before I get that `the connection was reset` error. Should I return false inside the catch, or somewhere else?

Comment: There is no option available to trace the problem faster.Here as I noticed  your connection time out value is 15sec.You can change it for some small value.Also use `setSoTimeout` method for socket timeout.

Comment: Even whith a lower connection time out, for some reason it takes just slightly over three minutes before it jumps to onPostExecute() That's why I'm thinking there must be something wrong with my code..

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpHost target = new HttpHost("192.168.2.3", 80);
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("/ping/login.php");

response = client.execute(target, post);
```

This solved the slow server response for me.